# How do I avoid "coupling" in OOP

Tags: c++, oop

OK, I'm not sure coupling describes truly my problem. The problem is, I'm creating my own 3d game engine based on ogre. I'm also using a physic library, PhysX, but since I need to create an abstraction layer between my main engine code and PhysX - so just in case we could use another physic engine - I decided to create a wrapper, Quantum.

- So ogre have an **Entity** class which will control the entity on the screen
- PhysX also have a **PxActor** class which contains the informations about the actor position in the PhysX works.
- The quantum wrapper will have a **QEntity** class which will act as a layer between the engine and PhysX
- Finally, the engine will have an **Entity** class which will have two members at least, the ogre entity object and the quantum entity. On each `update()` it will ask the QEntity what's up and update the ogre entity position.

Spot the problem? 4 classes for one entity? And remember that we need to access all four entities at least 60 times/s! So what about data partitioning? Not really optimised. Besides, there might be more classes, one for the AI,  one for the scripting engine...

Comment: I feel your pain. Each time I try to build a game and minimize coupling I end up with big chains of functions that only call other functions with a huge amount of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using objects of multiple classes to represent the same thing in multiple contexts is not a bad thing in itself. In fact, it would probably be worse if you had used the same object in all these contexts - for example, through some creative use of multiple inheritance.

Your `QEntity` class already does decoupling for you - as long as you program to its interface, and does not let classes specific to `PhysX` "stick out" from the interface of `QEntity`<sup>*</sup>, you are good.

It looks like your project introduces coupling in the "bridge" classes, which is exactly where it belongs. As long as you keep it there, your design would not have a coupling problem.

As far as 60 FPS goes, don't worry about it too much at the design stage. As long as there are no lengthy chains of responsibility relying on virtual functions, your compiler should be able to do a good job optimizing it for you.

<sup>*</sup> for example, `QEntity` shouldn't accept parameters or return objects that are specific to `PhysX`, except in a constructor that creates a "wrapper".

Comment: Thank you, so it's not bad finally. Just a question: will data partitioning work with such a pattern? I mean, the Ogre entity and the PxActor might be far from each other in memory, so the L3 cache would be useless.

Comment: @Vinz243 This depends on the implementation. If the two APIs require you to access Ogre entity and PxActor through pointers (as opposed to letting you use them as values) then the data may end up in different regions of memory. If they let you embed their objects inside yours, the two related objects would end up next to each other in memory. It's usually too early to reason about L3 cache effects until your are pretty close to code completion on at least a prototype, if not the actual system, and definitely too early before profiling and eliminating the "low hanging fruit" from your code.

Comment: A last question if you don't mind: since there are multiple entities, should I use namespaces or name the Quantum Entity QEntity?

Comment: @Vinz243 That's pretty much up to you: think what would give you better readability, and go with that. Personally, I'd use a namespace and also a prefix on `QEntity`,  because identifier `Entity` is too generic, with little descriptive value. I would even consider `QuantumEntity` as an alternative, to make the name more descriptive.